# how to differentiate the array values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have array listA and listB, compare and calculate the output of each list using javascript

```
listA=[1, 3, 5]
listB=[3, 3, 2] 

if listA[0] > listB[0] then x gets the point 1
if listA[1]==listB[1] then x and y no points
if listA[2] > listB[2] then y gets the point 1

function getPoints(x, y){
  var pointX, pointY =0
  var result = x.forEach(e=>{
   e[0] > y[0] ?  pointX++ : e[1] < y[1] pointY ++
 })
}

console.log(this.getPoints(listA, listB));
Expected Output

1 1
```

How to do this javascript, got stuck ,

Comment: `forEach` provides a second argument as the index `.forEach((e, i) => ...)`. You can use that to access the elements of the arrays. The `this` keyword in the `console.log` is not necessary.

Comment: Several issues here. 1) You really haven't provided a proper explanation of what *"compare and calculate"* exactly means in this scenario. 2) `Array#forEach() ` has no return 3) Your function has no return. Broken code is often not a good substitute for a proper explanation of exactly what you expect the code to do

Comment: What do you mean "compare and calculate the output"? What are you comparing? And what are you calculating?

Answer (score 1):

Using `reduce` will simplify. Build [accumalate points X, accumalate points Y]

```js
function getPoints(x, y) {
  return x.reduce(
    ([a, b], curr, i) => [curr > y[i] ? a + 1 : a, y[i] > curr ? b + 1 : b],
    [0, 0]
  );
}

listA = [1, 3, 5];
listB = [3, 3, 2];

console.log(getPoints(listA, listB));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what you want to get.

But I would suggest you to change little bit

so the script should go this way

```
 <script>
  const listA = [1, 3, 5];
  const listB = [3, 3, 2];

  // if listA[0] > listB[0] then x gets the point 1
  // if listA[1]==listB[1] then x and y no points
  // if listA[2] > listB[2] then y gets the point 1

  const point = { a: 0, b: 0 };
  function getPoints(x, y) {
    x.forEach((item, index) => {
      if (item > y[index]) {
        point.a++;
      }
      if (item < y[index]) {
        point.b++;
      }
    });
  }
  this.getPoints(listA, listB);
  console.log(point);
</script>
```

I took out pointA, pointB from the function and made an object that contains a and b as properties.
they will contain the total point of each parameter you pass through

hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

To compare arrays, use follow as code:

```
// Warn if overriding existing method
if(Array.prototype.equals)
    console.warn("Overriding existing Array.prototype.equals. Possible causes: New API defines the method, there's a framework conflict or you've got double inclusions in your code.");
// attach the .equals method to Array's prototype to call it on any array
Array.prototype.equals = function (array) {
    // if the other array is a falsy value, return
    if (!array)
        return false;

    // compare lengths - can save a lot of time 
    if (this.length != array.length)
        return false;

    for (var i = 0, l=this.length; i < l; i++) {
        // Check if we have nested arrays
        if (this[i] instanceof Array && array[i] instanceof Array) {
            // recurse into the nested arrays
            if (!this[i].equals(array[i]))
                return false;       
        }           
        else if (this[i] != array[i]) { 
            // Warning - two different object instances will never be equal: {x:20} != {x:20}
            return false;   
        }           
    }       
    return true;
}
// Hide method from for-in loops
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "equals", {enumerable: false});
```

Example usage:

```
[1, 2, [3, 4]].equals([1, 2, [3, 2]]) === false;
[1, 2,3].equals([1, 2, 3]) === true;
[1, 2, [3, 4]].equals([1, 2, [3, 4]]) === true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using reduce like this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```js
const listA = [2,34444,3];
const listB = [4444,33,2];


function getWinningPointsTally(listA, listB) {
  return listA.reduce((totalPoints, currentListAItem, index) => {
    if (currentListAItem > listB[index]) {
        totalPoints[0]++;
    } else if (listB[index] > currentListAItem) {
        totalPoints[1]++;
    } 
    
    return totalPoints;
  }, [0, 0]);
}

console.log(this.getWinningPointsTally(listA, listB))
```

Answer (score 0):

const calcPoints = (listA, listB) =>
listA.reduce((acc, p, i) => [acc[0] + (p > listB[i]), acc[1] + (p < listB[i])], [0, 0])

Answer (score 0):

A lot of ways to do this, but this should be simple and easy to understand. I chose a regular for loop since you are accessing the same index in each array.

```js
listA = [1, 3, 5]
listB = [3, 3, 2]

function getPoints(x, y) {
  var xPoints = 0, yPoints = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    if (x[i] > y[i]) xPoints++
    else if (x[i] < y[i]) yPoints++;

  return [xPoints, yPoints];
}

console.log(getPoints(listA, listB)); // output: [1,1]
```